# Get every combination of sort order and value of a csv

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I have a string with numbers separated by commas, like this:

```
Declare @string varchar(20) = '123,456,789'
```

And would like to return every possible combination + sort order of the values by doing this:

```
Select Combination FROM dbo.GetAllCombinations(@string)
```

Which would in result return this:

```
123
456
789
123,456
456,123
123,789
789,123
456,789
789,456
123,456,789
123,789,456
456,789,123
456,123,789
789,456,123
789,123,456
```

As you can see not only is every combination returned, but also each combination+sort order as well. The example shows only 3 values separated by commas, but should parse any amount--Recursive.

The logic needed would be somewhere in the realm of using a `WITH CUBE` statement, but the problem with using `WITH CUBE` (in a table structure instead of CSV of course), is that it won't shuffle the order of the values `123,456  456,123  etc.`, and will only provide each combination, which is only half of the battle.

Currently I have no idea what to try. If someone can provide some assistance it would be appreciated.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29661/sql-query-for-combinations-without-repetition

Comment: permutation is the word you are looking for I think :) https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Apermutation

Comment: Thanks @Donal that was perfect. Unfortunately it takes WAY TOO LONG for me even using CLR.  Was worth a shot though.

Answer (score 0):

I use a User Defined Table-valued Function called split_delimiter that takes 2 values: the @delimited_string and the @delimiter_type.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split_delimiter](@delimited_string VARCHAR(8000), @delimiter_type CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
WITH cte10(num) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)                         
,cte100(num) AS 
(
    SELECT  1 
    FROM    cte10 t1, cte10 t2
)
,cte10000(num) AS 
(
    SELECT  1 
    FROM    cte100 t1, cte100 t2
)
,cte1(num) AS 
(
    SELECT  TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@delimited_string),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM    cte10000
)
,cte2(num) AS 
(
    SELECT  1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.num+1 
    FROM    cte1 t
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(@delimited_string,t.num,1) = @delimiter_type
)
,cte3(num,[len]) AS
(
    SELECT  t.num
            ,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@delimiter_type,@delimited_string,t.num),0)-t.num,8000)
    FROM    cte2 t
)

SELECT  delimited_item_num  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.num)
        ,delimited_value    = SUBSTRING(@delimited_string, t.num, t.[len])
FROM    cte3 t;
```

Using that I was able to parse the CSV to a table and join it back to itself multiple times and use WITH ROLLUP to get the permutations you are looking for.

```
WITH Numbers as
(
SELECT      delimited_value
FROM        dbo.split_delimiter('123,456,789',',')
)

SELECT      CAST(Nums1.delimited_value AS VARCHAR)
            ,ISNULL(CAST(Nums2.delimited_value AS VARCHAR),'')
            ,ISNULL(CAST(Nums3.delimited_value AS VARCHAR),'')
            ,CAST(Nums4.delimited_value AS VARCHAR)
FROM        Numbers as Nums1
LEFT JOIN   Numbers as Nums2
    ON      Nums2.delimited_value not in (Nums1.delimited_value)
LEFT JOIN   Numbers as Nums3
    ON      Nums3.delimited_value not in (Nums1.delimited_value, Nums2.delimited_value)
LEFT JOIN   Numbers as Nums4
    ON      Nums4.delimited_value not in (Nums1.delimited_value, Nums2.delimited_value, Nums3.delimited_value)
GROUP BY    CAST(Nums1.delimited_value AS VARCHAR)
            ,ISNULL(CAST(Nums2.delimited_value AS VARCHAR),'')
            ,ISNULL(CAST(Nums3.delimited_value AS VARCHAR),'')
            ,CAST(Nums4.delimited_value AS VARCHAR) WITH ROLLUP
```

If you will potentially have more than 3 or 4, you'll want to expand your code accordingly.